# Returning multiple results from database query in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, executereader

I have the following code on my C# WinForm, which builds a query and passes it and a parameter to a function that queries the PostgreSQL database:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvCategories.DataSource);

List<string> validationInfoResult = new List<string>();
for (intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; intRowIndex++)
{
    strNewValueCat = dt.Rows[intRowIndex][1].ToString();
    db getValidationInfo = new db();

    strGetValidationInfoQuery = "SELECT validationdb, validationtable, validationfield, validationfield2, validationvalue2" +
                                " FROM masterfiles.categories" +
                                " WHERE category = @category";
    validationInfoResult = getValidationInfo.GetValidationInfo(strGetValidationInfoQuery, strNewValueCat);
}
```

As you can see, I'm iterating through a DGV's DataTable, grabbing a value from a particular cell in the current row and passing that as a parmaeter to the db query. I need to return values from 5 fields and my intention is to put the query result into a `List<>` and then get each of the `List<>` items into their own variable for use in the form.

My db class function looks like this:

```
public List<string> GetValidationInfo(string strQuery, string strCategory)
{
    List<string> strResult = new List<string>();

    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("category", strCategory));
        conn.Open();

        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                strResult.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                Console.WriteLine("reader: " + reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    return strResult;
}
```

I built the above code based on [this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743160/return-multiple-values-from-a-select-query).

When I run it, `Console.WriteLine()` only ever outputs the first query field, `validationdb` and then moves on to the next DataTable row in the calling `for` loop. Stepping through the code at runtime, after the first time it hits `Console.WriteLine()` it goes back to `while (reader.Read())` and then steps out of the `while` loop and returns to the calling function.

What is wrong in my loop that it's only putting the first query field result into the `List<>`?

Comment: You are only iterating through each ROW returned, not each COLUMN(field)

Comment: `GetString(0)` gets only the first column of every row.

Comment: @Kevin, I only need the value in one cell at the same index of each row to pass to the query each time.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai, How do I return all five query result fields to the calling function, then?

Comment: You could use a for loop within the while that goes from 0 to `reader.FieldCount`.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai - that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @mark I was talking about the same thing Anoop was. You were only outputting field 0

Comment: @Kevin - okay. sorry. I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Following code would output all fields:

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    // strResult.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    Console.WriteLine("Column 1: " + reader.GetString(0));
    Console.WriteLine("Column 2: " + reader.GetString(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Column 3: " + reader.GetString(2));
    Console.WriteLine("Column 4: " + reader.GetString(3));
    Console.WriteLine("Column 5: " + reader.GetString(4));
}
```

So you need to modify your output `List<string>` to accommodate 5 strings per item.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `GetString(0)` which fetches only the first column of a row (index 0). One way of getting around this would be by looping through the columns. From the [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlDataReader_FieldCount), `FieldCount` can be used to fetch the number of columns:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        strResult.Add(reader.GetString(i));
        Console.WriteLine("reader: " + reader.GetString(i));
    }
}
```